# PHP - What is the meaning of this syntax?

Tags: php, syntax

I tried to understand this line of code, but it is failed.

**$this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'**

I have no keyword to search for this kind of syntax.

What does it means.

1. How come they have "===" instead of "==" ?
2. How come they can do $this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG}, while, the FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG is a field of $this, it is not belong to $this-> request

The full code is

```
<?php
    class Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer {
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'showConfig';
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT = 'showConfigFormat';     

        private $request;

        public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {          
            $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
            if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'){
                $this->setHeader();
                $this->outputConfig();
            }
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG}` is interpreted by PHP as `$this->request->showConfig`. And the `===` is basically checking for equality in both value and type. Check this page to see the description of the triple equal signs http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Also, check this page http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php to see about variable variables in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'm almost crazy because of this kind of syntax

Answer (score 0):

`$this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG}` is same as:

```
$this->request->showConfig
```